# Multi-keywords field in a DT table in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I've a table with a keywords field linked to each entry, many with multi-keywords.
The keywords are currently delimited by semicolon like in the example below.

```
author  keywords
Shaw    Anticyclonic eddy; Arctic halocline
Eddie   Nonhydrostatic modeling
```

Is it possible to treat them independently in a way that when searching for one in particular, in a table made with the [DT package](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/), every entries where it is present is shown?

For instance, I want the user to be able to search for either "Anticyclonic eddy" or "Arctic halocline". The default search box in `datatables` treats this entry as one item: "Anticyclonic eddy; Arctic halocline", but I want it to be two separate, individually searchable items.

How should I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear how you want the text to be searched, or what you want returned from it, so an example output would be good.

However, from what you've described, it sounds like the 'search' box at the top of the `DT` does this for you

However, if you want your own control over it to produce a separate table, you can do:

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)

dt <- data.frame(author = c("Shaw", "Eddie"),
                 keywords = c("Anticyclonic eddy; Arctic halocline", "Nonhydrostatic modeling"))


function(input, output, session) {

    output$dt_data <- renderDataTable({
        dt_data <- dt
    })

    ## search dt for text
    output$dt_found <- renderDataTable({

        if(input$txt_search==""){
            dt_found <- NULL
        }else{
            txt <- input$txt_search
            dt_data <- dt

            dt_found <- dt_data[ grep(txt, dt_data$keywords), ]
        }
        return(dt_found)
    })
}
```

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)

dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(),
    dashboardSidebar(),
    dashboardBody(
        dataTableOutput(outputId = "dt_data"),
        textInput(inputId = "txt_search", label = "Search"),
        dataTableOutput(outputId = "dt_found")
    )
)
```